# DataTables warning: table id=mytable - An SQL error occurred: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found

Tags: php, ajax

anyone can solve this?
i move my localdata to server domain and fixing some problem, but i don't know how to fix this
i'm new in programing and this is ajax
thanks

DataTables warning: table id=mytable - An SQL error occurred: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'if0_35239935_pis_akademik.view_user' doesn't exist

maybe the table of database ?

Comment: It might be AJAX that is making the request, but your problem has nothing whatsoever to do with that. The problem is, as the message clearly states, that the table of the given name is not found in the database you connected to. `if0_35239935_pis_akademik` is the database name in that identifier, but I guess your database name on the live system is probably different.

Comment: Thanks, but i have 20 different table's and it's work, but not for this view_user. This is a table that contains user data to enter my website, I can log in but I can't see user data

Comment: Can't tell you more, than the error message already did. It does not find the table you want to read from, in the specified database. Check what really exists, pay attention to whether the combination of database and table name is correct ... and then double-check again.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the help